# How do I get the text string of Gtk.TreeSelection selected item?

Tags: c#, gtk#

Here is the code:

```
    protected virtual void OnTreeview3CursorChanged (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    TreeSelection selection = (sender as TreeView).Selection;
    TreeModel model;
    TreeIter iter;
    // The iter will point to the selected row
    if(selection.GetSelected(out model, out iter))
    {
        int selected_id = -1;
        string select_path = model.GetPath(iter).ToString();
        if (select_path.Contains(":")) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            selected_id = int.Parse(select_path);
        }
        TravTasks.TravTaskEditWidget task_edit_widget = 
            new TravTasks.TravTaskEditWidget(new TravTasks.TravellerTask(select_path));
```

All I want is the text at the selected item, not its index number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot this was answered here:
http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/gtk-sharp-list/2009-July/009796.html

So the answer is:

```
Console.WriteLine (model.GetValue (iter, 0);
```